# Which drashot require a mesorah?

Tags: halacha-theory, hermeneutics

From what I've heard, two of them have definite rules:

1. Kal Vachomer doesn't need a mesorah.
2. Gezeirah Shavah does need a mesorah.

But what about everything else, such as a Hekesh, or a Clal u'prat, or a Binyan Av?

Answer (score 8):

[Halichos Olam (shaar 4)](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=14769#p=35) quotes Rashi and Tosafos to [Sukkah 31a](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=7&daf=31&format=pdf), who disagree about this. Rashi (ד"ה לא מקשינן) says that only a kal vachomer can be thought up independently, but not any of the others. Tosafos (ד"ה ור"י) argue, and say that only gezeirah shavah requires a mesorah, but all of the others can be thought up independently.

[Yavin Shmuah, a little further on](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=14769#p=39), suggests that maybe Rashi's statement in Sukkah is only according to R' Yehuda, but that the Chachomim would say more like Tosafos, that you only need a mesorah for gezeirah shavah.